# Using Python, how do I list all the armatures in the scene and make the selected armature active?

Tags: python, armature, interface

I'll start by saying I'm fairly new to coding.
I'm trying to code an add-on that has a drop-down list that'll list all the armatures in a scene and then make it so you can select an armature from that list.
If you look the armature modifier, I'm after this type of list
[image: image of armature modifier]

Currently I'm using this

```
row.template_ID(context.view_layer.objects, "active")
```

[image]

This is getting me about 90% of the way there. I can list objects and make a selection, but instead I'd like it to only list armatures instead of including every object in the scene.

I found you could use this to make the selection only materials but failed to make it only selected armatures

```
row.template_ID(cobj, "active_material", new="material.new")
```

Then I tried using a prop_search

```
row.prop_search(scn, "lightRigSel",  bpy.data, "armatures")
```

[image]

I found that this got me the type of interface I wanted, but I couldn't figure out a way to make what was selected in the list it generated active.

Appreciate any help!